# ansi join on oracle 8i

Tags: oracle, ansi-sql, oracle8i

I've got this query in Oracle 8i:

```
 select
  decode(seqnum,
            1  , '1',
            cnt, '0'
        ) as                   value1,
  decode(seqnum,
            1  , t.BEGIN_DT,
            cnt, t.END_DT
  ) as                         TIME1,   
           t4.UNIT1 || '.SUBBATCH_TRIGGER' TAG     
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over(partition by t.BATCH_ID, t.plant_unit, t3.ID2 order by t.BEGIN_DT) as seqnum,
                   count(*) over(partition by t.BATCH_ID, t.plant_unit, t3.ID2) as cnt
              from SCH2.tb_pg_unit_stap t
    join (select ID1,batch_id from SCH2.VW_BATCH) t2 on t.BATCH_ID = t2.BATCH_ID
    join (select ID2,ID1 from SCH1.STEP) t3 on t3.ID1 = t2.ID1) t
    join SCH2.TB_W_MACHINE t4 on t4.plant_unit = t.plant_unit
    where (seqnum = 1
        or seqnum = cnt) AND (t.BEGIN_DT > '01-jan-2013' AND t.BEGIN_DT < '01-feb-2013');
```

I've recently asked the Stackoverflow community and they told me Oracle 8i doesn't support ansi joins.

how can I rewrite this query for Oracle 8i?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select decode(seqnum, 1 , '1',
                      cnt, '0') as value1,
       decode(seqnum, 1, t.BEGIN_DT,
                      cnt, t.END_DT) as TIME1,
       t4.UNIT1 || '.SUBBATCH_TRIGGER' TAG
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over(partition by t.BATCH_ID, t.plant_unit, t3.ID2 order by t.BEGIN_DT) as seqnum,
             count(*) over(partition by t.BATCH_ID, t.plant_unit, t3.ID2) as cnt
      from SCH2.tb_pg_unit_stap t,
           (select ID1,batch_id from SCH2.VW_BATCH) t2,
           (select ID2,ID1 from SCH1.STEP) t3
      where t.BATCH_ID = t2.BATCH_ID
        and t3.ID1 = t2.ID1) t,
     SCH2.TB_W_MACHINE t4
where t4.plant_unit = t.plant_unit
  and (seqnum = 1 or seqnum = cnt)
  AND (t.BEGIN_DT > '01-jan-2013' AND t.BEGIN_DT < '01-feb-2013');
```